# Is there a way to get the currently running activity from a service without the GET_TASKS permission in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a service which monitors the activity stack to get the top activity on the stack, and performs an action based on the top activity. I figured out a way to do this using the GET_TASKS permission. But the problem is that adding a new permission forces my users to manually update their application. So I wanted to know if there is any way to get the currently running activity without using the GET_TASKS permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The permission is there for a reason. The docs for that permission say:

> Allows an application to get information about the currently or recently running tasks.

and clearly you want to get information about currently running tasks, so you need this permission. Just explain in your release notes why you require the new permission and if your application has enough value to your users, they'll update it anyway.